# php adding child into parent

Tags: php, html

I have this data in my database
[image]

**My Target** is this to display that data in a table like this

[image]

I'm able to collect all of those data and display it in my HTML table but the things is I'm getting this.

[image]

I'm using array to get the user_id and the user type, and from that user ID i look for buyer, if got buyer under that ID, I display it, vise versa.

below are my code for your reference

```
$GparentType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'")->fetch_object()->type;

$ParentDetails = array();
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_id FROM profile WHERE Buy_From ='$user_id'");
while($resSql = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){          
    $ParentDetails[] = $resSql["user_id"];
}

echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"width:250px;margin:0 auto;\">
        <table class=\"table table-responsive table-hover\" border=\"1\">       
            <tr class=\"info\">
                <th style=\"width:20%;\">User</th>
                <th style=\"width:10%;\">Name</th>
                <!--th>Ordered</th>
                <th>Comm.&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Nett.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Payout</th>
                <th>Balance</th-->                      
            </tr>
            <tr class=\"parent success\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#child\" style=\"cursor:pointer\">                                  
                <td>".$user_id."<div style=\"float:right\">[".$GparentType."]</div></td>
                <td>".$uname."</td>
                <!--td id=\"total_order\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_comm\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_nett\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_payout\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_bal\"></td-->                                
            </tr>
            <tbody id=\"child\" class=\"collapse\">
            ";      
            getChild($ParentDetails);
            foreach($ParentDetails as $parent){

                $parentType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$parent."'")->fetch_object()->type;
                if($parentType == 'Retailer'){                      
                    $details = array();                     
                    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_id,Buy_From FROM profile WHERE Buy_From ='$parent'");
                    while($resSql = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

                        $details[] = $resSql["user_id"].",".$resSql["Buy_From"];
                    }                       
                    getChild($details);                         
                }                   
            }   
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

and the function

```
function getChild($details){    
$rate = $_POST['rate'];
include("conf.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, "supplier"); 

foreach($details as $newDetails){       
    $expDetails = explode(",",$newDetails);

    $uType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$expDetails[0]."'")->fetch_object()->type;
    $uName = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$expDetails[0]."'")->fetch_object()->name;

    if($uType == "Retailer"){
        echo "
            <tr class=\"danger\">
                <td>".$expDetails[0]."<div style=\"float:right\">[".$uType."]</div></td>
                <td>$uName</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
    else{
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$expDetails[0]."<div style=\"float:right\">[".$uType."]</div></td>
                <td>$uName</td>                                         
            </tr>
        ";
    }}}
```

**Please Help Me how can I achieve it, Thanks**

Comment: Please don't use images for displaying tables. Read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: this would be easier to understand if your expected output and result had the same order

Comment: can you show the $expDetails array content

Comment: Does this require recursion? Or does this task have a finite number of levels?

Comment: mickmackusa : if I understand u correctly, only 3 level of user, **Wholesaler, Retailer and Buyer,** **Buyer and Retailer** can be many, but only one **Wholesaler**

Answer (score 0):

from

```
   $details[] = $resSql["user_id"].",".$resSql["Buy_From"];
```

to

```
$details[$resSql["user_id"]] = $resSql["user_id"].",".$resSql["Buy_From"];
```

and before calling

```
getChild($details); to sort($details); getChild($details);
```

Comment: to sort array based on user_id properly....it's optional(if array is not  sorted properly based on user_id in worst case)

Comment: is my ans helpfull??

Comment: I'm still not getting what I want, by the way this is the $expDetails result //retailer
array (size=1)
  0 => string '7002' (length=4)
array (size=1)
  0 => string '7007' (length=4)
 
//Buyer
array (size=2)
  0 => string '7003' (length=4)
  1 => string '7002' (length=4)
  
array (size=2)
  0 => string '7004' (length=4)
  1 => string '7002' (length=4)

array (size=2)
  0 => string '7005' (length=4)
  1 => string '7002' (length=4)
  
array (size=2)
  0 => string '7006' (length=4)
  1 => string '7007' (length=4)

Comment: @Tony Please update the QUESTION instead of pasting unformatted data into a comment

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all,

after a few error, I manage to get as I wanted, what i did is simple just add a new function where that function will display the parent node(in this case Retailer) and call that function in getChild($details);
here how my code look like

```
$GparentType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'")->fetch_object()->type;

$ParentDetails = array();
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_id FROM profile WHERE Buy_From ='$user_id'");
while($resSql = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){          
    $ParentDetails[] = $resSql["user_id"];
}

echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"width:250px;margin:0 auto;\">
        <table class=\"table table-responsive table-hover\" border=\"1\">       
            <tr class=\"info\">
                <th style=\"width:20%;\">User</th>
                <th style=\"width:10%;\">Name</th>
                <!--th>Ordered</th>
                <th>Comm.&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Nett.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Payout</th>
                <th>Balance</th-->                      
            </tr>
            <tr class=\"parent success\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#child\" style=\"cursor:pointer\">                                  
                <td>".$user_id."<div style=\"float:right\">[".$GparentType."]</div></td>
                <td>".$uname."</td>
                <!--td id=\"total_order\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_comm\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_nett\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_payout\"></td>  
                <td id=\"total_bal\"></td-->                                
            </tr>
            <tbody id=\"child\" class=\"collapse\">
            ";      
            getChild($ParentDetails);
            foreach($ParentDetails as $parent){

                $parentType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$parent."'")->fetch_object()->type;
                if($parentType == 'Retailer'){                      
                    $details = array();                     
                    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_id,Buy_From FROM profile WHERE Buy_From ='$parent'");
                    while($resSql = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                        $details[] = $resSql["user_id"].",".$resSql["Buy_From"];
                    }                       
                    getChild($details);                         
                }                   
            }   
echo "</tbody></table>";

function getParent($details){   
$rate = $_POST['rate'];
include("conf.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, "supplier"); 

foreach($details as $newDetails){       
    //echo $details."</br>";
    $expDetails = explode(",",$newDetails);     

    $uType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$expDetails[0]."'")->fetch_object()->type;
    $uName = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$expDetails[0]."'")->fetch_object()->name;

    if($uType == "Retailer"){
        echo "
            <tr class=\"danger\" id=\"agent\">
                <td>".$expDetails[0]."<div style=\"float:right\">[".$uType."]</div></td>
                <td>$uName</td>
                <td id=\"subT_Ord\"></td>
                <td id=\"subT_Comm\"></td>
                <td id=\"subT_Nett\"></td>
                <td id=\"subT_Pay\"></td>
                <td id=\"subT_Bal\"></td>                               
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}}
```

and here is the changes getChild() function

```
function getChild($details){    
$rate = $_POST['rate'];
include("conf.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, "supplier"); 

$upline = array();
foreach($details as $newDetails){       
    //echo $newDetails."</br>";     
    $expDetails = explode(",",$newDetails);                 
    $upline[] = $expDetails[1];
}

if($upline){    
    $upline = array_unique($upline);
    getParent($upline);     
}

foreach($details as $newDetails){       
    $expDetails = explode(",",$newDetails);

    $uType = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$expDetails[0]."'")->fetch_object()->type;
    $uName = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM profile WHERE user_id = '".$expDetails[0]."'")->fetch_object()->name;

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$expDetails[0]."<div style=\"float:right\">[".$uType."]</div></td>
            <td>$uName</td>                                         
        </tr>
    ";
}}
```

I know its not a Pro-Programmer code, but now I reach my destinations.
thanks again.